# Implementing HTML5 clickTag

Tags: javascript, html

This should be easy, but I'm running into to problems with HTML5 clickTag for a standard web banner. It's not passing validation. Also, is there an HTML5 clickTag validator available online? This is what I have written for the clickTag:

```
var clickArea = document.getElementById("enter id here");
  clickArea.style.cursor = "pointer";
  var clickTag = "";
  clickArea.onclick = function() {
    window.open(window.clickTag, "_blank");
  }
```

Comment: Can you point to the documentation in the HTML5 spec for clickTag? I've never heard of it and can't find it in the spec at all.

Comment: ClickTag? Are you talking about Flash and [this](http://creative.adform.com/support/documentation/build-html5-banners/html5-banner-specifications/adding-clicktag-variables/)?

Comment: @Rob Here is a [draft](http://www.iab.net/media/file/HTML5_DAv1_0_Draft_05-06-13.pdf) I found. It's a pdf. Look at 2.4.1.

Comment: @Teemu No. This has to do with the google's push to drop Flash and move to HTML5 for banners.

Comment: That is not the HTML5 spec and even has incorrect information in the first few paragraphs.

Comment: Why does `clickTag` = `"clickTag"` and not a url as 2.4.1 describes?

Comment: @Madness clickTag is a string in which the ad trafficker will redirect to whatever url it needs to lead to.

Comment: Well, this clickTag passed verification. Maybe it was because I had clickTAG instead of clickTag. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Update: This clicktag did not pass verification. What is mossing?

Comment: Update: I updated the clickTag above and it passes verification. @Madness, I was incorrect and needed to keep the clickTag string empty.

Comment: Any answers to this question? The URL should not be hard-coded into the code. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Add below script inside the header of your HTML5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickTag = "_blank"; </script>
```

in the div "enter id here " in html5 add the onclick event:

```
onclick="window.open(window.clickTag)"
```

Example below,

```
<div id="enter id here" onclick="window.open(window.clickTag)" style="cursor: pointer"></div>
```

[Source](https://pragmaticwebmedia.com/ad-operation/how-to-add-clicktag-in-html5/45)

Comment: <div id="Enter id here" onclick="window.open(window.clickTag)" style="cursor: pointer"></div>